# JSONP via PHP return different than jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to retrieve cross-domain user data via JSONP, and getting different results via PHP and jQuery. First off, here is the JSONP being generated via PHP (with proper *header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'*) being passed):

```
hsAuthCallback({"planID":4,"memberPlan":"EMPLOYEE","memberName":"Fred"});
```

I'm trying two methods to retrieve it, first the **jQuery**, which works

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://url.com/path_to_file',
        jsonpCallback: 'hsAuthCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#jsOutput').text( JSON.stringify(data) );
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log("error("+jqXHR+", "+textStatus+", "+errorThrown+")");
        }
    });
});
```

Returns, as expected:

```
{"planID":4,"memberPlan":"EMPLOYEE","memberName":"Fred"}
```

Next is **PHP, where the problem lies** (I use a function to decode the jsonp)

```
// Decode JSONP (http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/01/11/php-and-jsonp/)
function jsonp_decode($jsonp, $assoc = false) { 
    if($jsonp[0] !== '[' && $jsonp[0] !== '{') { 
        $jsonp = substr($jsonp, strpos($jsonp, '('));
    }
    return json_decode(trim($jsonp,'();'), $assoc);
}    
$url = 'https://url.com/path_to_file';
$jsonp = file_get_contents($url);
$plan_data = jsonp_decode($jsonp, true);
var_dump($plan_data);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  ["planID"]=>
  int(0)
  ["memberPlan"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["memberName"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I've tested using an actual json file over S3 and it seems to work. I have limited control over the generated JSONP. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($jsonp)`?

Comment: You could probably echo json_encode(jsonp_decode($jsonp, true)); , as you want the php page to return json data

Comment: @Barmar I get: `string(61) "hsAuthCallback({"planID":0,"memberPlan":"","memberName":""});"`

Comment: @JayRizzi That gives me: `{"planID":0,"memberPlan":"","memberName":""}` again void of the proper data...

Comment: The problem is at the API end, it's responding with empty values. Your PHP code is parsing it properly.

Comment: does the API require any authentication or cookies?

Comment: Yes, the problem was the API side, and the fact that I somehow overlooked the fact that js is client side and php is server side. One of the flaws of running tests against static content!